# Why do I get indexoutofboundsexception when iterating PropertyInfo using pex?

Tags: c#, pex

I have the following method:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(vRS rs) where T : class, new() {
    T o = new T();
    Type tp = typeof(T);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in tp.GetProperties()) {
        string name = getBlParameterName(pi);
        Type pt = pi.PropertyType;
        if (pt == typeof(string)) {
            String s = rs.getString(name);
            //try {
                  pi.SetValue(o, s, null);
                //pi.SetValue(o, s, (object[])null);
            //} catch {
                //throw new Exception("" + o.GetType().FullName);
            //}
        } else if (pt == typeof(int)) {
            int i = rs.getInt(name);
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(int?)) {
            int? i = rs.getInt(name);
            if (i == int.MinValue) i = null;
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(short)) {
            short i = (short)rs.getInt(name);
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(short?)) {
            short? i = (short)rs.getInt(name);
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(DateTime)) {
            DateTime dt = rs.getDate(name);
            pi.SetValue(o, dt, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(DateTime?)) {
            DateTime? dt = rs.getDate(name);
            if (dt == DateTime.MinValue) dt = null;
            pi.SetValue(o, dt, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(decimal)) {
            decimal i = rs.getDecimal(name);
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        } else if (pt == typeof(decimal?)) {
            decimal? i = rs.getDecimal(name);
            if (i == decimal.MinValue) i = null;
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        }else if (pt == typeof(bool?)) {
            bool? i = null;
            var charBool = rs.getChar(name);
            if (charBool != null) {
                if (charBool == '0') {
                    i = false;
                } else if (charBool == '1') {
                    i = true;
                }
            }
            pi.SetValue(o, i, null);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Pex exploration returns an exception in the following part of code:

```
if (pt == typeof(string)) {
    String s = rs.getString(name);
    pi.SetValue(o, s, null);
}
```

I cannot understand why do I get:

> System error: Index was outside the bounds of the array` exception.

Shall I add any PexAttribute or PexAssume? Could you please help?

"name" is in "rs" and is not equal to null but the problem is in line: 'pi.SetValue(o, s, null);'

Comment: Please reformat your code more usefully - see the help for details, and don't use tabs. It would also help if you could reduce this code to a *minimal* example which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only line that could be failing is `String s = rs.getString(name);` since it is accessing an array. See why `name` is not in rs - or verify it exists before asking for it.

Comment: "name" is in "rs" and is not equal to null but the problem is in line: 'pi.SetValue(o, s, null);'

Comment: Can you get the value? `pi.GetValue` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx. This post http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/reflection-propertyinfo-getvalue-know-its-indexed-property-t3226804.html discusses some possible issues with the error you are receiving. Possibly related to index parameters.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that I don't use pi.GetValue but pi.SetValue(o, s, null); Is it somehow connected ? It doens't happend when I debug the code. It only happends when PEX does its explorations, so I'm wondering if PEX platform has some bug or it is something wrong with my code.

Comment: You should use `GetValue` to make sure the value exists prior to setting it.